# bulk insert with were clause in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three database tables - Roles, Permissions and rolePermissions as below.

```
Permissions
|---------------------|------------------|
|      name           |        id        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|   THREAD_VIEW       |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|   TEAM_VIEW         |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|   TEAM_EDIT         |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|

Roles
|---------------------|------------------|
|      name           |        id        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      ADMIN          |        11        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      MEMBER         |        12        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     EMPLOYEE        |        13        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|   FRONT DESK        |        14        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     GATE KEEPER     |        15        |
|---------------------|------------------|

rolePermissions
|---------------------|------------------|
|      roleId         |    permissionId  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         11          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         11          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         12          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         12          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         13          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         14          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         15          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want to write a query to add permission `TEAM_VIEW` (id-2) for the roles on which `THREAD_VIEW` (id-1) permission is already active. As we can see in `rolePermissions` table `roleId` 11 already has `permissionId` 2 and i have to add `permissionId` 2 for `roleId` 12 and `roleId` 14.
I am very beginner in MySQL. i wrote something but that does not work.

```
insert into rolePermissions(roleId, permissionId) 
select rp.roleId, p.id from rolePermissions rp
join Permissions p on p.id = rp.permissionId
where p.name = 'THREAD_VIEW' and p.name <> 'TEAM_VIEW';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
insert into rolePermissions(roleId, permissionId)
select r.roleId, p.permissionId
from roles r
inner join permissions p on p.name = 'TEAM_VIEW'
where exists (
    select 1 
    from rolePermissions rp1
    inner join permissions p1 on p1.id = r.permissionId
    where p1.name = 'THREAD_VIEW' and rp1.roleId = r.id
)
```

This inserts the new tuple for roles that already have the `'THREAD_VIEW'` permission.

If you want to ensure that the new tuple does not yet exist in the target table, then, assuming that you have a unique key on `roleId, permissionId`, you can just add an `on duplicate key` clause at the end of the query:

```
on duplicate key update roleId = values(roleId)
```